# Can a black hole ever be the output of a Feynman diagram in momentum space?

Tags: black-holes, momentum, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

For a Feynman diagram representing a collision, particles come in from infinity with certain momenta, collide and then go off to infinite with other momenta. At collision vertices we integrate over all space-time.

It seems to me, that no in-coming or outgoing particles can be combined states if those states have any kind of half-life, because after infinite time they will decay. So even Feynman diagrams with protons incoming protons can only be approximate. (assuming proton decay)

Equally, if a black hole evaporates, can a black hole ever be one of the incoming or outgoing states?

As I read it, we could only have elementary particles as input and outputs, with perhaps a black hole forming during the collision which lasts for a certain amount of time (even a billion years) and then evaporating and elementary particles coming out.

In other words, in quantum gravity, should the S-Matrix contain only information about colliding elementary particles or include colliding black holes?

Comment: What quantum field theory are you using in which "black hole" is an allowed state at all?

Comment: @ACuriousMind A hypothetical QFT which includes black holes! If no such QFT could exist the answer would be "no". You can have QFT with protons which are combined states so why not black holes?

Comment: A black hole is supposed to be in mixed states because it has entropy.

Comment: @zooby Why are protons related with black holes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Feynman diagrams are generically used for theories with weak coupling. As such, the "in" and "out" states must be "free fields" (the fields one gets when canonically quantising the field). This means essentially that Feynman diagrams capture "weak effects" since the S-matrix expansion only works **perturbatively** (such that the expansion makes sense).

Now, when one thinks of the S-matrix of gravity, they're thinking of the scattering of gravitons **perturbatively**. In practice this means that you have to consider small fluctuations around flat space ("weak effects").

To answer your question now, black holes are a strong effect effect of gravity and thus cannot be represented by calculations involving weak effects, such as Feynman diagrams. The in/out states must be free fields (such as quarks, photons, or even gravitons if naively quantised) and since black holes are interactions between gravitons (which are by no means weak), they cannot be represented by free states in a Fock space.

Scattering amplitudes in string theory make sense at high-energy whereas those in quantum field theory may break down. Essentially this is how one can capture black holes in string theory, because it can describe those strong effects. But Feynman diagrams are not present in string theory and one usually integrates over the worldsheet of a certain process.

I'll summarise by answering more directly your questions.

- "Equally, if a black hole evaporates, can a black hole ever be one of the incoming or outgoing states?" 
  No, since it is not a free state. Even in practical S-matrix calculations for protons one approximates by using the composite quarks (approximation: the quarks are treated as free (but actually are not), so one can use them as in/out states). Even a small amount of time from our perspective is to captured well by us assuming the states are defined at +/- infinity (this is why decay etc. is not a huge problem for the S-matrix).
- "in quantum gravity, should the S-Matrix contain only information about colliding elementary particles or include colliding black holes?"
  In general the S-matrix should only contain information regarding the states of the Fock space. In the case of quantum gravity, this would be graviton states (plus other matter states if your theory contains more fields), which will be well-defined on the Fock space. So the S-matrix will not contain information about black holes, only gravitons + matter. In one could somehow include gravity into the standard model then the S-matrix would contain information only about the elementary particles and gravitons.

Answer (score 1):

Let us be clear that any Feynman diagram of calculation implies quantization of gravity, for which there is no standard model yet.

That said, it is true that the standard model can be embedded in string theory models and also true that string theory  can accommodate quantization of gravity by including the  graviton in its string excitation.

[Here micro black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole#Man-made_micro_black_holes) have been considered as a prediction of the extra dimensions of string theories, to be checked at LHC.

> Such quantum black holes should decay emitting sprays of particles that could be seen by detectors at these facilities. A paper by Choptuik and Pretorius, published in 2010 in Physical Review Letters, presented a computer-generated proof that micro black holes must form from two colliding particles with sufficient energy, which might be allowable at the energies of the LHC if additional dimensions are present other than the customary four (three spatial, one temporal).

For example in [this calculation](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0106295) they use semiclassical arguments to estimate the generation and decay of micro black holes at the LHC energies, based on the extra dimensions of string theories, thus connecting the standard model interactions with gravitational interactions.

The CMS experiment has been looking for them ["Search for black holes and other new phenomena in high-multiplicity final states in proton-proton collisions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01403)

> Semiclassical black holes and string balls with masses as high as 9.5 TeV, and quantum black holes with masses as high as 9.0 TeV are excluded by this search in the context of models with extra dimensions, thus significantly extending limits set at a center-of-mass energy of 8 TeV with the LHC Run 1 data.

Various string model predictions are tested. If you read the links, it is not simple Feynman diagrams, but extensions of such calculations within string theory models. In this sense colliding black holes can be accommodated.All this is highly speculative of course, as only just limits are given at the moment.

Comment: It's all very interesting. Not quite an answer to the question though!

Comment: I wanted to convey that S matrix and Feynman diagrams become complicated in string theory models , which do treat black holes equivalently to elementary particles, but the mathematics is more complex.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. Because it doesn't say black holes can be treated as things that zoom in from infinity go into an interaction then zoom back out to infinity.

Comment: If you could handle the mathematics, you could make such a model. It would be strings scattering off strings .

Comment: this came up in  a search : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwixnqTQkf_eAhXLY1AKHeSKBOsQFjAJegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783319002149-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1411620-p175009322&usg=AOvVaw0mjPq6UhfuG8ZwUcgFRzXr

Comment: @anan yes but how can a black hole go off to infinity, because a black hole decays over time. Only things which are eternal such as electrons and photons can come in from infinity.

Comment: When one calculates with quantum mechanical models large distances are *assumed*to be infinity, for example scattering Kaons(they decay) from protons.If you want to nit pick, you could only calculate for the few stable particles in the standard model table. this is a different question than whether there exist quantum mechanical calculations for black holes.

Comment: Given that we know there are higher energy cosmic rays than particles in the LHC, wouldn't there have been observations of micro blackhole evaporations already?

Comment: @CriglCragl  to separate gluon and quark jets from microblack hole evaporation signatures needs a controlled experiment, which cosmic rays are not. i.e.one needs incoming four vectors and outgoing four vectors and for cosmic rays we only have outgoing.

Comment: @anna v Does the search and not finding of primordial blackholes suggest additional constraints? Wouldn't there be impacts cosmologically if this could happen below a given level, and it may be one well beyond what we can achieve?

Comment: @CriglCragl all this are tentative models , when gravity is definitievely quantized, not just effectively, maybe there will be answers to such questions, as the constraints on the models would be much stronger. Now it is easy to change limits and boundaries and change models.